# How to change login screen in CrunchBang?

Tags: crunchbang, login-manager

I am on SLiM, and I don't like the default login screen. I want a login screen like the one shown below:

[image]

But instead I have a pretty minimal one which has just one textbox and nothing else on the screen. I can't find a screenshot of it, but that is what I got when I am done installing.

Is changing to GDM the only way to get a login screen like this? Is there any other way?

Comment: I found the answer to my own question fortunately and I posted it as answer in the hope that this might help someone else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found that this is possible by editing the `slim.conf` file available in `/etc`.

You would need admin credentials to open this file.

SLiM themes are placed in `/usr/share/slim/themes`:

[image]

In the `slim.conf` file, there is a section that mentions the theme:

```
# current theme, use comma separated list to specify a set to 
# randomly choose from
current_theme       crunchbang
```

You can change this to any of the themes shown in the previous screenshot.

Change the theme and exit the file. Try logging out and logging back in.

That's it. Login screen is changed with immediate effect.

More information available here: http://slim.berlios.de/

Answer (score 2):

The SLiM website has a page detailing how to [create your own theme](http://slim.berlios.de/themes_howto.php).

You can find additional themes on a number of sites, including [Gnome Look](http://gnome-look.org/) and in the [Arch User Repository](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?O=0&K=slim-theme&do_Search=Go)...

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way would be to install GDM, beacuse the login manager is much more better than slim, Slim has LITERALLY no scrollbars... or anything. You cannot change your window manager or desktop enviroment either. (On slim) I preffer GDM, since its more reliable and easy to use. It does not require editing the configuration file AFTER logging in to change the de/wm.